# MySQL not using all key parts of composite index

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, composite-key

I have an InnoDB table containing ~1.7m rows in **MySQL 5.7.19**. I want to optimize the following query:

```
select * from `table` where `col1` = 'x' and `col2` = 123 and `col3` = 'z'
```

where the columns are defined as (all using utf8mb4 encoding):

```
col1 varchar(255) null
col2 varchar(255) not null
col3 varchar(255) not null
```

and an index over all columns:

```
key (
  col1, -- Cardinality: 40
  col2, -- Cardinality: 472810
  col3  -- Cardinality: 403767
)
```

I'd expect the query to run fast, because MySQL should be able to fully utilise the index. Now, the performance is not so good and it starts to make sense when I run the query with `explain format=json`:

```
"used_key_parts": [
   "col1"
],
"key_length": "1022"
```

Only the first column of the composite index is utilised. The constraints on `col2` and `col3` are evaluated using a table scan.

Could anyone explain to me what is going on here and give advice on how to improve on this?

I currently solved it by merging columns into one column, by introducing and indexing a stored generated column that concatenates `col1` and `col2`. However, I can not use this for queries that want to use the `IN()` operator on those columns.

Thank you in advance!

Jarno

Comment: Did you try to force the index with `USE INDEX (index_name)`?  
And a note: low cardinality columns are not a good candidates for indexes, I'd change the key's column order `(col2, col1, col3)` if its possible

Comment: Thanks for your insight regarding cardinality. Forcing the index did not change anything, because the right index was already used, just not all columns of the index. The problem was related to an integer not being cast to a string before comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
`col2` = 123
```

is your undoing.  When comparing a `VARCHAR` to an integer constant, the varchar is converted to numeric.  This requires converting *all* relevant rows on the fly.

After all, `col2` could contain `"0123"` or `"123.0"` or `"1.23e2"`.  As strings those are quite different; indexes on varchars are sorted according to *string* attributes (`COLLATION`).

The likely solution is to change to add quotes:

```
`col2` = "123"
```

The order of the `ANDs` in the `WHERE` does not matter.

The order of the columns in the `INDEX` does matter.  Having an `INDEX` with `col1` and `col3` first, in either order, would be better.

Cardinality does matter when comparing `INDEX(col1)` versus `INDEX(col3)`.

Cardinality does *not* matter for the parts of the index actually used, as when comparing `INDEX(col1, col3)` versus `INDEX(col3, col1)`.

In contrast, `WHERE int_col = "123"` *will* convert `"123"` to `123` be able to use an index.

Answer (score 1):

try build you composite  using high cardinality columns

eg:

```
col2,col3,col1
```

and do the fact you are using AND operator in where don't need  the ()  aroudn the condition

```
  select * from `table` where `col1` = 'x' and `col2` = 'y' and `col3` = 'z'
```

and last  you could impose the index  with FORCE

Comment: Thanks for your insight regarding cardinality. Forcing the index did not change anything, because the right index was already used, just not all columns of the index. The problem was related to an integer not being cast to a string before comparison.

Comment: You mean that the value you used in where is different type  to the value in db  .. Obvoiusly  the index  don't work  .. you must avoid  each type of conversion for use the index

Comment: And  if you have  a look at my answer  you can see that already contain the proper data type  ..  base un your schema  .

Comment: Yes, you were absolutely right, thank you scaisEdge. The accidental use of different types was an oversight from my side.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your reply. After playing around with the column order in the index (related to cardinality) I noticed that the application was comparing with an integer value on `col2` (which is a varchar column). Casting the value to a string solved the performance problem.